How to implement Turn Based Logic in Socket.io
I am unable to make turn based logic in socket.io rooms, I can make them communicate but i don't know how to assign roles and make the player wait till the other player finish their turn
Here is the problem with the example of TicTacToe.
Problem 1 : I know how to make 2 clients communicate with each other via sockets, but right now its not turn based, both the users can do their move any given time
Problem 2 : How to assign a role to a particular client, like one person is 'O' and other is 'X', i thought of handling in the server side, but then, state of 1 game(2 players playing in a room) can conflict with the other game (another 2 people playing somewhere else)
In this stackoverflow answer, he made a players array, what happens when more than 2 people try to join, then the array will be filled with multiple users that we don't want in a 2 player game, and if we stop the user from joining then only 2 player can play the game at a time on the whole server.
I'm not able to find an optimal solution for this particular problem, am I missing something?


Perhaps you can set up an object to keep track of the current player's turn. Set up your client's socket to send its move and a unique player id to the server side. On the server side, upon receiving the request, check the object and deem if it's the particular player's turn, implement a simple if else here only to allow actions to be made only if the correct player id is sending the request, change the object to point to the other player id once done.

Arrays will not be sufficient for this. You can use an object and generate a unique sessionId string as the 'key' and other data you may need such as 'role' or 'turn' as the value into the object. Using this, for each game, you would only access the nodes within the correct parentNode (sessionId), allowing multiple instances of the same game to occur.


edit: An array in an array could work but using objects would be better for indexing lol.
Im still quite new to sockets, but I think this simple implementation would work for you.
